# Compiler error in a java weight conversion program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm working on a Weight Conversion GUI program. I'm getting few compiler errors. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below are the error log:

```
Frame4a.java:32: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       ^
Frame4a.java:36: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    double kp= Double.parseDouble(strkilo);
    ^
Frame4a.java:38: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    if(k.isSelected()){ ans=(kp/2.24);
    ^
Frame4a.java:40: error: class, interface, or enum expected
           area.settext( kp + "kilograms = " + ans + " pounds");
           ^
Frame4a.java:41: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
Frame4a.java:47: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        area.settext( kp + "pounds =" + ans +" kilograms");
        ^
Frame4a.java:48: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
7 errors
```

Can I get some light on these please?

I updated code and now I'm getting these:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame4a implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Weight converter");
        JPanel p = new JPanel(); // Make a JPanel;
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea() ;
        JRadioButton k,Po;
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        k=new JRadioButton("kilograms to pounds");
        Po=new JRadioButton("pounds to kilograms");
        k.addActionListener(this);
        Po.addActionListener(this);

        p.add(area);
        p.add(k);
        p.add(Po);
        p.add(field);

        f.getContentPane().add(p); // Add panel P to JFrame f
        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String strkilo = field.getText();
        double kp= Double.parseDouble(strkilo);
        if(k.isSelected())

        { ans =(kp/2.24);
            area.setText( kp + "kilograms = " + ans + " pounds");
        }
        else
        {
            double ans=(kp*2.24);
            area.setText( kp + "pounds =" + ans +" kilograms");
        }
    }
}
===================
Now the error log:
===================

Frame4a.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        k.addActionListener(this);
                            ^
Frame4a.java:20: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Po.addActionListener(this);
                             ^
Frame4a.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        String strkilo = field.getText();
                         ^
  symbol:   variable field
  location: class Frame4a
Frame4a.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        if(k.isSelected())
           ^
  symbol:   variable k
  location: class Frame4a
Frame4a.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        { ans =(kp/2.24);
          ^
  symbol:   variable ans
  location: class Frame4a
Frame4a.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
            area.setText( kp + "kilograms = " + ans + " pounds");
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable ans
  location: class Frame4a
Frame4a.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
            area.setText( kp + "kilograms = " + ans + " pounds");
            ^
  symbol:   variable area
  location: class Frame4a
Frame4a.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
            area.setText( kp + "pounds =" + ans +" kilograms");
            ^
  symbol:   variable area
  location: class Frame4a
8 errors
```

Comment: Did you declare a class?

Comment: Could you show the code please?

Comment: It seems you missed a matching `{` in your class declaration.

Comment: @Sridhar it seems more like the whole class declaration is missing, otherwise the compiler would complain about a missing `{`

Comment: I added a pic of my code (unfortunately couldn't add the code in the main question, so put a screenshot instead) @abarison

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't put these methods in a class.  Looking at the filename, it needs to be something like this:

```
public class Frame4a implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        double kp= Double.parseDouble(strkilo);
        if(k.isSelected()){ 
            ans=(kp/2.24);
            area.settext( kp + "kilograms = " + ans + " pounds");
        } else {
            area.settext( kp + "pounds =" + ans +" kilograms");
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't account for other errors in your code, e.g. `settext()` is probably `setText()`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have an extra closing `}` just before your `public void actionPerformed(...)` method call. The method is basically outside the scope of the `Frame4a` class, so you will get weird compilation errors like the ones you showed.